# Кортеж массивов в один массив

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

Ниже привожу кусок кода, генерирующий данные, которые я хотел бы перевести в numpy массив с длиной (-1)

```
from jax import random
def random_layer_params(m, n, key, scale=1e-2):  
  w_key, b_key = random.split(key)
  return scale * random.normal(w_key, (n, m)), scale * random.normal(b_key, (n,))


def init_network_params(sizes, key):
  keys = random.split(key, len(sizes))
  res = [random_layer_params(m, n, k) for m, n, k in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:], keys)]
  return res
```

Когда я вызываю np.array на данных, я получаю ошибку, потому что нельзя сложить массивы длиной (10,4) и (10,). Как отрешейпить массивы по отдельности я тоже не понимаю.
Пример получаемой структуры данных:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, код как вы собираете массив Numpy. Можно просто добавить к массиву размером 10х4 ваш вектор размером 10.

Comment: @Volk это было бы замечательно, но я не понимаю как обратиться к этим массивам

Comment: Я не очень понимаю часть вашего кода. Приложите вместе с библиотеками, что вы используете. У библиотеки random нет метода split.

Comment: @Volk `from jax import random`

Comment: что такое "длина (-1)" и что, по-вашему, должно получиться при сложении массивов размерностью (10,4) и (10,1)?

Comment: @strawdog хочу получить одномерный массив, где будет записаны  все числа из  двух массивов

Comment: ну вот вы мне логику объясните на пальцах, что с чем, по-вашему, будет складываться при сложении двумерного массива с одномерным?

Comment: @strawdog мне не нужно ничего складывать. Я хочу расположить числе первого массива в ряд, а потом дописать числа второго массива, чтоб получился один одноименный массив, в котором записаны числа из двух предыдущих массивов.

Answer (score 2):

вы можете воспользоваться методами `ravel` или `flatten` для массивов numpy, либо просто сделать решейп и конкатенацию. Например, так:

```
res = np.concatenate((a.reshape(a.shape[0]*a.shape[1]), b))
```

где a - соответственно двумерный массив, а b - одномерный.

Answer (score 1):

Если речь о двух массивах, то можно применить append

```
tup = (np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]]), np.array([5, 6, 7, 8]))
out = np.append(*tup)
print(out)
```

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
```